# unable to click enter string using python

Tags: python

i have a problem with this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#Getting local session of Chrome
driver=webdriver.Chrome()

#put here the adress of your page
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in")
#put here the content you have put in Notepad, ie the XPath



elem=driver.find_elements_by_name('q')############### this is one of name 
elem.send_keys("google search through python")



driver.close()
```

Output is showing elem list is empty 
why Am I getting null list?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google.py", line 14, in <module>
    elem.send_keys("google search through python")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

can anyone help me track the problem?

Comment: `elem` is a **list** of all elements with name "q". Pick the one you want to apply `send_keys` on. For example, change your code to `elem[0].send_keys("bla")`.

Answer (score 0):

use this one to see if errors occur

```
elem=driver.find_elements_by_name('q')
for e in elem:
    e.send_keys("google search through python")
```

Comment: Hi Amir, Thanks it is working fine. But I have issue in my HTML page I don't have name I have id and it is not working with id   .

Comment: <button id="emailTab" class="btn btn-md btnTabSelected" ng-class="{true: 'btnTabSelected', false: 'btnTabDeselected'}[emailSelected]" ng-click="emailTab()">Email</button>

Comment: unable to locate input id="email-file-upload"